# securely accepting html in mysql

Tags: mysql, html, security

I allow some HTML tags to be used in my form. How can ensure my database (mysql) is safe, when using php to insert this data into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use prepared statements to escape it for sql and htmlentities when outputting it to html.

[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130323#130323)

Comment: so, this'll allow them to use statements such as <b> bold </b> safely? I already use mysqli_read_escape_string and htmlentities when inputting and html_entities_decode when outputting, is that a good idea?

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_String will protect your database and htmlentities (with ENT_QUOTES) will protect your html

Comment: just dont forget to kick out any string with a <script> tag

Comment: htmlentities takes care of the script tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but there should be some helper functions that will help.  Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks from working.  That will prevent the first danger.  The second is to sanitize the HTML to only allow the tags you deem safe.  I.e. all  tags and form tags should be removed, as well as tags that would ruin the layout of your site.  You'll have to find the library method to do this.